# Warning при использовании JSON-simple

Tags: java, json

При использовании JSON-simple в Java, IDEA подсвечивает в следующем коде вторую строку с инспекцией.

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("type", "abilityStatus");
```

Инспекция говорит:

```
Unchecked call to 'put(K, V)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.HashMap'
```

Проблем при компиляции и работе это не вызывает, но хочется разобраться, что не нравится IDEA-е и как это поправить.

Кто сталкивался с таким и знает, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот warning возникает у всех пользователей org.json.simple из-за того, что библиотека не использует generics. Скрыть warning можно конструкцией `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Если хочется сделать "правильно", можно использовать что-нибудь вроде [Google GSOn](https://github.com/google/gson)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548656/unchecked-call-to-adde-as-a-member-of-the-raw-type-arraylist-and-hashmap